# Оперативная память заполняется пока ОС не зависнет

Tags: c++, память, sdl, sdl2

Суть в том, что какая-то функция выделяет память, но не удаляет её. Ещё я знаю что проблема в функции draw класса Window или в функциях, которые draw использует для себя.

Исходный код возможно проблемных функций я выложу сюда, а весь остальной код на pastebin

```
void Window::draw(Object toDraw)
{
SDL_RenderCopy(coreRenderer, convertSurfaceToTexture(toDraw.getSurface(), coreRenderer), NULL, NULL);
}

SDL_Texture *convertSurfaceToTexture(SDL_Surface *image, SDL_Renderer *ren)
{
SDL_Texture *texture;
texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, image);
if(texture == nullptr){
    std::cout << "Ошибка конвертирования SDL_Surface  в SDL_Texture: " << "\n\t" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
return texture;
}
```

Так как у меня нет баллов репутации, дам [ссылку](http://pastebin.com/9zPKff9N), где будут содержаться ссылки.

Comment: 1) Учитесь читать документацию. 2) Учитесь отлаживать свои программы.:)

Comment: Так я уже долго бьюсь :) Если я это делаю вручную без всяких самопальных "обёрток", всё в норме. Да и память вроде везде где надо освобождается

Comment: А отладчиком я пользуюсь :)

Comment: Если у вас есть классы, которые в качестве членов данных имеют указатели, то для этих классов вы должны по крайней мере явно написать конструктор копирования, копирующий оператор присваивания и деструктор.

Comment: В коде у меня не работает только она функция. Я просто не понимаю где ошибка. Ну, конструктор копирования я не удосужился сделать, но проблема всё-равно не в этом

Comment: Что значит не работает? Это ваша функция или из библиотеки? Если это библиотечная функция, то читайте документацию, а если ваша, то используйте отладку.

Comment: Функция моя. Отладка никак не помогает. Всё что я с помощью неё узнал, это то, где проблема

Comment: Если это кому-то нужно (Что мало вероятно), то SIGSEGV был не по моей вине. Оказалось, что он его даёт и на простых задачках на алгоритмизацию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё правильно у Вас память съедается, Вы создаёте текстуры и никогда их не удаляете. На каждый вызов `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` должен быть соответствующий вызов `SDL_DestroyTexture`.

---

Вероятно, Ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
auto texture = convertSurfaceToTexture(toDraw.getSurface(), coreRenderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(coreRenderer, texture , NULL, NULL);
SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
```

Я бы Всё это сделал через `unique_ptr`, но это уже Вам решать.

P.S. Я не разбираюсь в SDL, но по логике вещей на данном этапе уже можно удалять текстуру.

Comment: После return выполнение функции невозможно. Как тогда можно вызвать SDL_DestroyTexture для texture, если я уже вне функции?

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, обновил ответ

Comment: Хм, отладчик говорит про SIGSEGV и кидает на функцию convertSurfaceToTexture

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, я в Вашем коде сделал минимальные изменения, если там был SIGSEGV, значит он перенёсся в мой код. Откуда он там берётся — разбирайтесь с отладчиком.

Answer (score 1):

convertSurfaceToTexture выделяет новый объект SDL_Texture, который никто не удаляет и не сохраняет - это явная утечка

Comment: Тоесть надо сохранять то, что выдаёт convertSurfaceToTexture в отдельную переменную, использовать, а потом удалять?

Comment: 'void Window::draw(Object toDraw)
{
    SDL_Texture *texture = convertSurfaceToTexture(toDraw.getSurface(), coreRenderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(coreRenderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
}' Как-то так получается?

Answer (score 1):

И ответ, традиционный для подобных вопросов.

> Отладка никак не помогает.

Значит, нужно добавить к отладчику ещё и инструменты для отслеживания ошибок работы с памятью. Для C-разработчика они не просто дополняют отладчик, они используются наравне с ним как основной инструмент. Про C++ не скажу, пишу на нём мало.

1. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (консоль, небольшое [описание на русском](http://alexott.net/ru/linux/valgrind/Valgrind.html))
2. [Valgrind для Windows](https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind4win/wiki/Home/)
3. [Большой список подобных утилит на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/) (Windows)
4. [Отлов ошибок работы с памятью в Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf(v=VS.100).aspx)
5. [Отлов ошибок работы с памятью в Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/valgrind/) (Linux):

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плюс к ним - статические анализаторы кода, которые в некоторых случаях ещё до запуска программы могут отловить потенциально опасные места (например, перезапись значения указателя, в который сохраняется выделенная память).

Comment: Спасибо, не знал о таких средствах :)

Comment: А для qtCreator под linux нет ничего такого?

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, вроде есть: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-valgrind-overview.html (сам не проверял, ибо креатором не пользуюсь) И ещё приятная новость: https://habrahabr.ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/313498/